# AND filter on crossfilter array dimension

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm using the [new array dimensions in Crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays) and I'm running into trouble trying to make a filter that selects only rows that include multiple array values. It's pretty easy to make a filter that selects the union on array values using a custom filter function:

```
var ndx = crossfilter([
    {arrayVals: [1, 2]},
    {arrayVals: [2, 3]},
    {arrayVals: [1, 2, 3]}
]);
var arrayDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.arrayVals;}, true);
arrayDim.filter(function(d) {return d == 1 || d == 3;}).top(Infinity);
```

However I'd really like to filter on the intersection of multiple conditions (e.g. `d == 1 && d == 3`). I know I can accomplish this by setting up a separate dimension for each conditional I want to `&&` together, but that seems very wasteful. Is there a way to do this without having to resort to multiple dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this was down-voted. Basically, the answer at this time is "no", to the best of my knowledge. However, you don't need to create a new dimension for each conditional - just one dimension that is not of the array type. Something like:

```
var arrayDim2 = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.arrayVals;});
arrayDim2.filter(function(d) { return d.indexOf(1) !== -1 && d.indexOf(3) !== -1;});
arrayDim2.top(Infinity);
```

Then just keep adding new conditionals to your filter function.

Comment: The array dimensions were working really well with dc.js, which is one thing leaving the array as an array will make more difficult. But if that's what it takes I'll figure out how to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @Singularity You may be able to do both.  Use an array dimension and groups for dc.js charts and a standard dimension just for your intersection filters.